# How to copy the conditional formatting of another cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have following table in Google Sheets with conditional formatting in the 2nd row. I would like to make the first row colored the same way as the second one.

[image]

Is there any option how to dynamically "copy" format of another cell?

I just do not want to do it manually all the time - like 5 conditional formatting for cells A1:L1 where will be `=IF(A2<350)` then use color1. If `A2<300` use color2. And so on...

Edit:
The main point, that c0de removed from my question by editing, is that I want to use the **Color scale** option in conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

Select and copy a cell the has the formatting you need, select the range you want to copy the formatting to, right click, choose 'Paste special' - 'Conditional formatting'.

Or, you can open the conditional formatting sidebar and edit the rule to add an additional range.

--

If I misunderstood the first time:

If you want the first row to be the same colour as the second (not copying the rules) then 'lock' the row that is checked by the formula. Apply `=IF(A$2<350)` to range A1:L2.

Notice the `$`. This tells the formula to check row two only.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I am using the Color scale option. I want to use it. That is the point. Am I able to do it like that?

Comment: Add the $ and see if that does what you need. :)

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand where should I add the $ to? Could you show me directly in a test sheet, please? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iJT1gHQX8ws0q_9wnFbUsB6u7z5SxHuZAK5tKqLSMk0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you see in my answer A$2?

Comment: Yes I do. Do you see any `if` in my test sheet?

Comment: Finally in front of a computer to see your sheet. I see what you mean. This cannot be done as far as I know. You could have several conditional formats with custom formulas to do this.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much and sorry for misunderstanding. I am very glad I have an answer but sad for the result :)